# Parsing XML response of SOAP call in Weblogic

Tags: java, xml, soap, weblogic, jaxp

We are in the process of migrating functionality from a Weblogic Server **8,1 sp5** with java 1.4 to 10.3.6 with java 1.7.

The case that is described below is working properly in the old server, however we are facing an issue when transferring the handling to the new one.
The problem lies while retrieving and parsing an XML response that was retrieved from an external system through SOAP calls.

*The following libraries and procedure are used in the method:*

1. **java.net.HttpURLConnection** to make the connection
2. **java.io.OutputStream** to send the request
3. **java.io.InputStream** to get the response
4. **byte[]** to store the result before transforming in to **String**
5. **javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder**, **java.io.StringReader** and **org.xml.sax.InputSource** to transform the String into **org.w3c.dom.Document**
6. The following exception is thrown:
   **"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException - Content is not allowed in trailing section."**

**When opening the logs of the application with notepad++ many null characters appear after the end of the file which seem to cause the issue. I repeat that no such cases appear when executing the request from the old server.**

*The respective code is the following:*

```
//Creating the connection
URL u = new URL(default_server);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soap_action);

OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

wout.write(xmlString);
wout.flush();
wout.close();

InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

int c = in.available();
byte r[] = new byte[c];
in.read(r);
String response = new String(r);
connection.disconnect();

//Transorming the String to XML Doc
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(response);
InputSource theInputSource = new InputSource();
theInputSource.setCharacterStream(theReader);
Document doc = builder.parse(theInputSource); 
//Here occurs org.xml.sax.SAXParseException-Content is not allowed in trailing section

return doc;
```

I know that i can solve the issue by getting the stripping the response from junk characters but this not a safe resolution.
Do you have any information to share on the matter? Do you think it is a java version issue or maybe a server configuration issue?
Thank you in advance your time.

Best Regards,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues

- `in.available()` as per the javadoc: Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes... Do not rely on this. Loop over buffers of 8K to read the stream until you reach the end or even better, do not re-invent the wheel, use commons-io from Apache and use a single call to `ÌOUtils.read`
- `String response = new String(r);` doing this you are assuming that the bytes received are encoded using the same charset as your platform encoding/charset. It is unlikely to be the case if you are on Windows or OSX. You must pass the charset and use the constructor `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`.

Comment: Very helpful response. I do not understand why this problem appeared only in the new environment but it seems that the problem was the estimation of length from in.available(). Thank you very much for your indication!

Comment: Please accept the response then; this is good for your kharma